# Help identifying non Lego blocks

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I'm in the UK. I've been given a box of old Lego bricks from when I was a child (80s). These were mixed in. I seem to recall they made a house perhaps? They are larger than Lego, smaller than Duplo (Lego and Duplo block included for size comparison). The 'studs' on top are hollow. They had clip-on wheels in the set and window-like push-in inserts. I cant find any names or identifying  marks. Has anyone got any ideas what they are?

[image: Top]
[image: Underside]

Comment: Judging by this website, they appear to not be "American Plastic Bricks" by Elgo: https://www.madeinchicagomuseum.com/single-post/halsam-products-co/